# Why does AlertDialog.Builder not have setOnDismissListener or setOnShowListener methods?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to use the fluid interface of AlertDialog.Builder but when I get to the point of adding my DismissListener and ShowListener I have to break out and add it to the dialog object after I do my create() on the builder. Does anyone know why they're not on there? I can't extend it because of the private P member... It's not the end of the world or anything, I'm just curious why it's not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API level 17. you can use `setOnDismissListener (DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener)` method

Answer (score 7):

Have You Tried this method..

```
AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
lg.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
@Override
public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
//Do some work
}
});
return dlg;
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I do the add after my .create() call.. I would just rather be able to do:  new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle(title).setMessage(msg)
                        .setPositiveButton(buttonTitle, listener).setDismissListener(dismissListener).show()

Comment: @danb You do it after the create() call, but on the Builder object? That ain't gonna work. create() is how the Builder gives you an AlertDialog, but a Builder object itself does not have any methods for setting listeners on them.

Comment: The builder has several methods for setting listeners, just not the two I mention. It has setOnCancelListener, setOnItemSelectedListener and setOnKeyListener.. I am just curious why the api seems incomplete.

Comment: public AlertDialog.Builder setOnDismissListener (DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener)

Added in API level 17