# Execution doesn't wait to Alertdialog.dismiss()

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application and I have this question:

**How can I do to make execution waits until user has selected an option from an `AlertDialog`?**

This is my code:

```
    if (mPerson== null)
    {
        mPerson = new Person();
        AlertDialog dialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message_select))
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title_attention));
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.male, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                mPerson.setGender(Gender.male);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.female, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1)
            {
                mPerson.setGender(Gender.female);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    // TODO: Show data.

    getWidgetsRefereces();
    customizeLayout();

    loadSpinnerValues();
```

After `dialog.dismiss()` I have to execute this:

```
    // TODO: Show data.

    getWidgetsRefereces();
    customizeLayout();

    loadSpinnerValues();
```

Comment: What you have to execute after dialog's `dismiss()`?

Comment: Also you can implement `OnDismissListener` to your AlertDialog and put those function in it.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944585/why-does-alertdialog-builder-not-have-setondismisslistener-or-setonshowlistener

Comment: +1 for editing question name and content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
 AlertDialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message_select))
    .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title_attention));
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.male, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            mPerson.setGender(Gender.male);
            dialog.dismiss();
            postSelection();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.female, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1)
        {
            mPerson.setGender(Gender.female);
            dialog.dismiss();
            postSelection(); 
        }
    });

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Call this method once the selection is complete.

```
public void postSelection(){
getWidgetsRefereces();
customizeLayout();
 loadSpinnerValues();
}
```

Comment: He can just put those methods after dialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of event based execution. If you want some code to execute when you press a button, then wire it to do so. Place the code in question in a method that you can call whenever you want.

Generally, when you are programming on Android, you need to adhere to the event based nature of the platform. Traditional procedural sequential thinking will lead you to dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize your dialog interface like this .
You should use onDismissListener on dialog interface.Dont make it anonymous.

```
private class MyDialogInterfaceMethod implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener,DialogInterface.OnDismissListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                //when user click a button 

            }
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //put your code here 


            }

        }
```

Than use it on your alert dialog like this

```
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new MyDialogInterfaceMethod ());
```